# Saving images directly to Dropbox using 'Cloud Save'?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is there any way to save the images or any file to a specific Dropbox folder? Right now it just save files to Dropbox and they also get downloaded on my local disk.

I have a folder on Dropbox which doesn't sync with my local computer. I want to save files directly to that folder.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way built into the existing Cloud Save extension. But, if you're willing to modify the existing extension, you can pretty easily modify the folder that Cloud Save will save to.

**0. Install Cloud Save extension.**

I'm going to assume you already have the extension installed. But just in case.

**1. Make a Copy of the Cloud Save extension.**

1. Go to the **Extensions** page ( chrome://settings/extensionSettings ).
2. Enable **Developer Mode** (check box up top).
3. Make note of the **ID** of the Cloud Save extension.
4. Make a copy of the extension directory some place, like your desktop. The extension directory will have the same name as the extension ID, something like "dlbemabjbfhjcccahjioenmkgimjbbkd".
5. To locate the extensions directory, see this article on extension locations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250163/how-do-directly-modify-a-google-chrome-extension-file-crx It'll be different based on your OS.

**2. Modify the Cloud Save Extension**

1. Using your temp copy of Cloud Save...
2. Navigate into {temp directory}/{version number}/hosts/dropbox/
3. Open the **dropbox.js** file with your favorite text editor.
4. Find the line containing **var folder = ''**
5. Change the location. For example, if you had a folder within your Dropbox folder called CloudSave, you could change the line to read **var folder = 'CloudSave'**.
6. Save the file.
7. Go back into the Chrome **Extensions** page, with **Developer Mode** still activated.
8. Press the **Load unpacked extension** button.
9. Locate and open your working copy of the extension.
10. This should take the place of the old installed Cloud Save and now save to your desired location.

Note: I had trouble using folder names with spaces in them. Just something to keep in mind.

Hope that helps!

Comment: it didn't work, i was able to edit the extension file you mentioned above. Then i Loaded unpacked extension which was successful but file still doesn't save in that folder(var folder = 'abc').